# Chaining iostream operators in c++

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string w;
    cin >> w;
    w += " World";
    cout << cout << ' ' << cin << ' ' << w << endl;
};
```

The output produced when "hola" is the user input:

```
hola
1 1 hola world
```

Why is `hola` produced on the first line? I understand that the second line is the result of successful `cout`, `cin` and the concatenated string.

Comment: Didn't you type `hola` on your keyboard and pressed enter on the first line?

Comment: My guess is that the bool operator for the (wrong) cout and cin in the chain produces the two 1 in the output. But I need to check.

Comment: I cannot check, because it does not compile, as expected. I wonder which compiler eats this.

Comment: @KamilCuk ahhh yes lol thanks

Comment: @ArminMontigny i compiled it with g++ ...

Comment: Now, I found it. I checked with old GCC compiler and pre C++11. This compiled. So, it is the "old" C++ version. I checked with compiler explorer. The compiler generates code and calls the `operator void*() const` which returns a non NULL pointer in case that the stream state is OK. And this is shown as 1. Cool.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Well, it's not a matter of old *compiler*, but just [old standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (see e.g. [Clang 13](https://godbolt.org/z/xjcf7obdj)). Please consider expanding the comment in an answer.

Comment: @Bob Right. Correct. This is what I wanted to express with "old C++ version." Sorry for the sloppy language . . .

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string w;
  std::cin >> w;

  std::cout << w << " world\n";
}
```

Reading and printing are two separate steps, you don't chain them.

Comment: I was just trying to play around with the values of `cin` and `cout` as boolean.